# Intercepting SWF (Adobe Flash Player) data

Tags: flash

A third party web site displays streaming alphanumeric data in a Flash application (.swf). I would like to capture that data to be used in my own desktop application. Is this possible? If yes, then what are my options e.g. using VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

A first thing to try is to use wireshark or a similar tool to see what the application is doing with the servers. Make sure the browser cache is empty first. Then try to do what the application does in your own code.